# UISearchBar should not dismiss Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I'm building an iOS app, and I get to a `UITableViewController` with a `UISearchController` [2] by performing the following transition from another view controller [1]:

```
let search = UITableViewController()
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: search)
self.present(nav, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

However, when I press the "cancel" button in [2], The app pops the entire navigation controller and goes back to view [1]! How do I get it to just cancel the search instead of popping the entire navigation controller away? I feel like this should be the default behavior and I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you're surprised. You are saying `present` to create a modal (presented) view controller consisting of the navigation controller and the table:

```
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: search)
self.present(nav, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

What you are `present`-ing is `nav`, the navigation controller. So what's the reverse of that? It's `dismiss`, where what you are `dismiss`-ing is `nav`. So would I would *expect* the navigation controller to vanish at the end.

The real problem here is probably that what you are doing is not at all how you use a UISearchController. The search controller is *itself* a view controller, and *it* should do the presenting of the results table view. You are just not handling it correctly to make it do that. You have not shown anything about your search controller and its configuration so it's impossible to help with further specifics.